# 2d parallax edges

Tags: algorithm, parallax-scrolling

I'm writing a mini 2d game, the scene background is based on two images with parallax effect.

I want the right edge of both images, finish at the same time matching the right edge of the canvas. But I've got, both images finish on the canvas left edge.

I'm doing:

```
parallaxQuotient = nearImage.width / farImage.width;
```

And scrolling like this:

```
speed = 1;
farImage.position.x -= speed / parallaxQuotient ;
nearImage.position.x -= speed ;
```

How to get both images ending on canvas right edge?

Comment: Trying to rephrase: You want the images to loop horizontally?

Comment: No, the scene should end when the nearImage.pos.x reaches canvas rigth edge.

Comment: So you want to change the size of your scene such that it ends where the parallax background would end when scrolled to the end? Or do you want to change your parallax background sizes to match a known scene size? (It would be really helpful if you could draw it.)

Comment: mmm.. i want to change the size of my scene. but no the viewport of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you get (left image align) is correct given the math you use.

What you want is that when near image is reaching right edge:

```
nearImage.position.x == nearImage.width - viewPort.width
```

we have also far image reaching right edge :

```
farImage.position.x  == farImage.width - viewPort.width
```

All that should happen in the same time, so the speed ratio should be

```
speedRatio = ( nearImage.width - viewPort.width ) / (  farImage.width - viewPort.width )
```